# How to use shortUrl as parameter in href on each condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [jquery-bitly-plugin](https://github.com/gumayunov/jquery-bitly-plugin) for shorten some URLs and I'm doing in this way:

```
var opts = {login: myLogin, key: myKey},
    bitly = new $.Bitly(opts);

shorten = bitly.shorten(url, {
    onSuccess: function (shortUrl) {
        console.info(shortUrl); // this works fine
                                // I got something like http://bit.ly/1DfLzsF
        return shortUrl;
    },
    onError: function (data) {
        console.log(data.errorCode, data.errorMessage);
    }
});
```

Then I tried this:

```
console.log(shorten);
```

But got `Undefined`, why? How do I assign the var in order to use in other places?

**EDIT: adding extra information around the problem**

This info will clarify a bit what I'm trying to do with my question so I have this code which allow to share some content in social networks on click event:

```
$('.share-item').click(function () {
    var href = '',
            url = base_url + 'main/show/' + imgUrl.split("/")[2].split(".")[0];

    if ($(this).data('category') == 'share-facebook') {
        href = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + url;
    }
    else if ($(this).data('category') == 'share-twitter') {
        text = 'SomeText';
        via = 'SomeText2';
        href = 'http://www.twitter.com/share/?text=' + text + '&amp;via=' + via + '&amp;url=' + url;
    }
    else if ($(this).data('category') == 'share-mail') {
        $('#finalImgModal').attr('src', imgUrl);
        $('#image').val(imgUrl);
        $('#mailModal').modal('show');
        return false;
    }

    window.open(href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');
    return false;
});
```

As you may notice `url` is common to `share-facebook` and `share-twitter`. I need to shorten that URL and pass back to the `href` on each possible choice. For shorten the URL I'm using [jquery-bitly-plugin](https://github.com/gumayunov/jquery-bitly-plugin) as follow:

```
var opts = {login: myLogin, key: myKey},
    bitly = new $.Bitly(opts);

bitly.shorten(url, {
    onSuccess: function (shortUrl) {
        console.info(shortUrl); // this works fine I got 
                                // something like http://bit.ly/1DfLzsF
    },
    onError: function (data) {
        console.log(data.errorCode, data.errorMessage);
    }
});
```

How I can use `shortUrl` in `href` parameter? Do I need to repeat the code on each condition in order to use execute the action at `onSuccess` event from `shorten()` method? How do you deal with this?

Comment: because the last `console.log(shorten);` is executed even before `onSuccess` is completed

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla and? What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Call other places from inside `onSuccess`.

Comment: put `console.log(shortUrl);` inside the onSuccess function.

Comment: What he/she is saying is that this call is asynchronous, you can only get the value after the call has completed.

Comment: Also on a more trivial note, `bitly.shorten` doesn't return anything, it is unreasonable to expect the variable `shorten` to contain anything but `undefined`. The only place where there is anything significant is `shortUrl`, which is a completely different variable (and only available inside the `bitly.shorten` callback). The `return shortUrl` is shouting into the wind - no-one is using what that function returns.

Comment: With the code found in your duplicate submission, it is still not clear to me where you want to use the bitly code - in facebook, twitter, mail, or a new `if` branch that you haven't written yet? Or do you want to open a bitly-shortened window if facebook or twitter, but avoid bitly-shorten on mail?

Comment: @Amadan Just in `facebook` and `twitter`, `mail` condition doesn't depends on `shorten()` function result but in `.share-item` click event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign to a variable:

```
var opts = {login: myLogin, key: myKey},
    bitly = new $.Bitly(opts);

bitly.shorten(url, {
    onSuccess: function (shortUrl) {
        shorten = shortUrl;
    },
    onError: function (data) {
        console.log(data.errorCode, data.errorMessage);
    }
});
```

The method `shorten` doesn't have a return on source code of plugin.

**IMPROVED ANSWER**

Based on your edite post, this is the correct answer on how to use it the shortUrl:

```
$('.share-item').click(function () {
    var href = '',
        url = base_url + 'main/show/' + imgUrl.split("/")[2].split(".")[0],
        opts = {login: myLogin, key: myKey},
        bitly = new $.Bitly(opts);

    bitly.shorten(url, {
        onSuccess: function (shortUrl) {
            if ($(this).data('category') == 'share-facebook') {
                href = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + shortUrl;
            } else if ($(this).data('category') == 'share-twitter') {
                text = 'SomeText';
                via = 'SomeText2';
                href = 'http://www.twitter.com/share/?text=' + text + '&amp;via=' + via + '&amp;url=' + shortUrl;
            } else if ($(this).data('category') == 'share-mail') {
                $('#finalImgModal').attr('src', imgUrl);
                $('#image').val(imgUrl);
                $('#mailModal').modal('show');
            }

            if ($(this).data('category') != 'share-mail')
                window.open(href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');
        },
        onError: function (data) {
            console.log(data.errorCode, data.errorMessage);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: This is correct but often useless, since the rest of the code won't know when `shorten` is available (unless it is being periodically polled, which is suboptimal). The best solution is to either invoke the continuation code from within `onSuccess`, or alternately trigger an event so that the outside world knows `shorten` now has something someone might want.

Comment: @Amadan can you elaborate a question with your solution?

Comment: Simple - instead of `shorten = shortUrl`, put `doSomethingWithShortURL(shortUrl)` (first option; the second option is a tiny bit more complicated). Still, as I said, this is a correct answer, +1.

Comment: @Amadan can `doSomethingWithShortURL` be something like `doSomethingWithShortURL(newUrl) { return newUrl; }` and then assign to a var? I'm still a bit lost at this point. See my edit

Comment: It is not possible. What do you want to do with `shortUrl`? Don't say "assign it to a variable", that is useless. Good answers: "show it to the user", "redirect the browser", "store it into the database"... When you figure out what you want to do with it, just do it right there and then (or call a function that will do it).

Comment: Trying to store it into a variable is like telling a friend to call a cinema and see if they have available seats and tell you, then go out of town and switch off your mobile phone. The rest of the code won't know when you store it in the variable, and it will likely not be at the time when you are trying to use it.

Comment: @Amadan give me some minutes, I will edit the main post adding more info

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, you need to figure out a future for the shortened URL. This future here is "open a window with this URL". Here is a quick pseudocode:

```
function openWindow(shortUrl) {
  window.open(shortUrl, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');
}

$('.share-item').click(function () {
  if ($(this).data('category') == 'share-mail') {
    ...
    return;
  }

  if (....twitter...) {
    href = ...
  } else if (....facebook....) {
    href = ...
  }

  bitly.shorten(url, {
    onSuccess: openWindow,
    onError: function(err) {
      ...
    }
  });
}
```

(I made the `openWindow` future into a separate function to make it obvious, but it could just as well have been left inline.)